# ComplexType within a ComplexType and setting properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I am using the following ComplexTypes:

CityStateRegion.cs

```
public class CityStateRegion
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int Zip { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Airport { get; set; }
    }
```

Address.cs

```
public class Address
    {
        public string AddressOne { get; set; }
        public string AddressTwo { get; set; }
        public CityStateRegion Area { get; set; }
    }
```

The reason why I broke these into two separate complextypes is b/c I want to use the `CityStateRegion` in some Entities while needing the full address in others...

```
public class Person
    {
        public Guid PersonId { get; private set; }
        public CityStateRegion Location { get; set; }
    }
```

versus

```
public class Company
    {
        public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I found that I had to do the following in FluentApi to make sure all fields relating to `Area` came across as required:

```
//Address ComplexType Configurations
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
 .Property(a => a.AddressOne).HasMaxLength(100).IsOptional();
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
 .Property(a => a.AddressTwo).HasMaxLength(100).IsOptional();
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
 .Property(a => a.Area.State).IsRequired(); //CityStateRegion
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
 .Property(a => a.Area.City).IsRequired(); //CityStateRegion
//... more props omitted
```

Then I wonder... what is the difference between the following?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
  .Property(c => c.Address.Area.City).HasMaxLength(50).Required();
```

vs

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
  .Property(a => a.Area.City).HasMaxLength(50).Required();
```

vs

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<CityStateRegion>()
  .Property(a => a.City).HasMaxLength(50).IsOptional();
```

The problem is - sometimes it should be required and other times it shouldn't.

To recap:

1. Is a nested `ComplexType` typical?
2. What's the standard way of setting `ComplexType` properties if they change depending on which Entity is using them? I don't believe I have much of a choice in options but wanted to see how others would set this up. Does one property setting trump the next? I had troubles finding the answer on MSDN and don't feel like trying out three different migrations.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using composition and not inheritance for this task? Wouldn't be more clean and simple to have `class Address : CityStateRegion`?

Comment: Turns out inheritance doesn't work with ComplexTypes.